# Does the intermediate AI cheat?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does the intermediate (or beginner for that matter) AI in League of Legends 'cheat' and get more gold than normal?  I just finished a game where team meat popsicle was up 47 kills (and 60 assists) to 27 (and 27) and had 150 more minion kills and 40 more neutral kills, but trailed gold earned by 57.9k to 71.0k.

More generally, I've heard that you can't really "feed" the AI (gold that is, experience is another matter), as they will always get the same items at some predefined time regardless of how much gold they actually have.  Is this true?  What's going on?

Comment: While I don't know the exact mechanics behind it (which is why I'm not posting an answer), I can confirm that it doesn't matter *how* hard you prevent the AI champions from farming, or *how* long they spend dead -- their item builds are not tied in to a farm-based gold mechanic, but rather one of time.

Comment: Their _levels_, on the other hand, are not time-based. Meaning it is still useful to push them out of lane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Red Post on the following forum thread, but it pretty much describes the different apparent "cheats" that happen on this game mode.
http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1124284

As Raven Dreamer stated, they get items on a scheduled basis, whether or not they have very low K/D ratio, this is one of the principal facts of making Coop. vs Ai more challenging that the actual custom games.

Answer (score 4):

All bots cheat, they receive items on a pre-determined schedule according to their level, regardless of their farm. Their farmed gold is mostly meaningless to them. The trick is zone them and make them under-leveled, so they don't receive their pre-set items.